# Flutter проблема с отображением счетчика документов firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, count, firestore

У меня немного не хватает опыта с выводом данных Firebase
имеется запрос в firestore на счетчик данных в коллекции он выглядит вот так (взят и немного корректирован с официальной документации)

```
final fs = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
fs.collection("users").count().get().then((users) => print('${users.count}'),
);
```

Помогите с выводом его в Text()
Классический вывод конкретных данных с коллекции понятен для меня, но тут любая попытка вводит меня в ступор, я не очень сильный спец во Flutter и хотел бы видеть небольшой пример как я могу это реализовать

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.